# Flutter firebase messaging getAPNSToken function returns null always

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement firebase flutter notifications for iOS. getAPNSToken always returning null. I have tried after adding delay function as well it's still returning null.

I have done following things to fix issue but no success:

1. Enabled push notification for the target from Xcode.
2. Enabled background fetch & remote notification option.
3. Created push notification certificate(both for sandbox & production) on developer.apple.com
4. In Firebase console : Project settings -> Cloud messaging : Uploaded APN's auth key & APN certificate. Only APN's auth key should work as per description but uploaded both.
5. Notification permission is granted from the dialog appear when open app.

Please help. I am unable to find out nay solution why it's its returning null.